# What is the difference between the two err value?

Tags: string, go, methods, go-interface

I'm trying to understand golang interface, my problem is that why err2.What undefined.

Here is a simple code. The output indicates that both err and err2 have same type as *main.MyError, but err2 have no field "What", so there must be some difference between err and err2, but I cannot figure out the difference here. I just began learning golang not long before, any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "time"
        "reflect"
)

type MyError struct {
        When time.Time
        What string
}

func (e *MyError) Error() string {
        return fmt.Sprintf("at %v, %s",
                e.When, e.What)
}

func run() error {
        return &MyError{
                time.Now(),
                "it didn't work",
        }
}

func main() {
        err := &MyError{time.Now(), "Hello"}
        fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(err))
        fmt.Println(err.What)   

        err2 := run()
        fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(err2))
        fmt.Println(err2.What)
}
```

## expected output:

`main.MyError`
 
`Hello`
 
`main.MyError`
 
`it didn't work`

## actual output:

`\# command-line-arguments
./test.go:34:18: err2.What undefined (type error has no field or method What)`

Answer (score 1):

The function `run()` returns a value of type [`error`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error), which is an interface type. Yes, it wraps a value of concrete type `*MyError`, but to get access to `MyError`'s fields, you need to use a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions):

```
fmt.Println(err2.(*MyError).What)
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/OV4TH_cgsD6).

Note that a value of `error` type may contain values of other concrete types, actually any that implements the `error` interface. If it would contain a value of another type, the above type assertion would result in a runtime panic.

If you're unsure `err2` actually holds a value of type `*MyError` and you want to avoid the runtime panic, you may use the special form of type assertion to get this information and only act if it is so:

```
if myerror, ok := err2.(*MyError); ok {
    fmt.Println(myerror.What) // Here myerror has static type *MyError
} else {
    fmt.Println("Some other error:", err2)
}
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/K7rs3giZQUr).

Comment: Thanks, that works! So does that means the run() function just return an error type which wraps a value of *MyError instead of the &MyError written in the run function code block.

Comment: @Cyanic `&MyError` is not a type, it's the address operator applied on a composite literal, which results in a value of type `*MyError`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the interface of error type is let you use `Error()` method without any detail in the concrete structure. You can check on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cOBcYBiGHKq)